# Get Spring embeded database content

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, h2, imdb

I created a H2 In-Memory Database in Spring framework like this:

```
  EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
  EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) //.H2 or .DERBY
            .addScript("create-table.sql")
            .build();
```

I would like to make another Java application which connect to this Database and access the data from that.

I can connect to the database with this code:

```
Connection connecton = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb","sa","");
```

But this returns me an empty database, without tables and records.

[Here is a description](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-embedded-database-examples/) which tell how to solve this problem.

Unfortunately I cannot understand how to do work with *Spring container* and the `MethodInvokingBean`, because I don't know where to code, how to use, how it works etc.

I would appreciate that someone make a short tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Did you test first application?

Comment: Yes I did and works fine. I can get records without problems.

Comment: Does the second application run DDL scripts similar to first application? I meant creating/altering tables. If so, it would wipe out the data persisted by first application. If you are using second application just for reading data, you can use read-only mode.

Comment: Java isn't using any .dll file. Read-only mode is nothing to do with a database connection conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a TCP server to share the database. Adding following configuration:

```
<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
  <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,-tcpPort,9092"/>
</bean>
```

Once the server start up, other Java application can connect to it using `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:testdb`

Comment: Can you tell me where to but this XML code? How can I opean the this bean XML?

Comment: For spring boot app, you can add XML configuration using `@ImportResource(value="classpath:/package/filename.xml")`. [Here is a example](http://javarticles.com/2016/02/spring-importresource-annotation-example.html)